# Is there a way to change esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(TIME_TO_SLEEP);

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

this is my first time posting here and sorry if i do not post in the correct category .
I want to ask you if there is any possibility to change

```
#define TIME_TO_SLEEP 5; 
to 
#define TIME_TO_SLEEP yourInputString = readFile(SPIFFS, "/inputString.txt");
```

In the "/inputString.txt" is a number like 30 . I want to be able to put that number in the TIME_TO_SLEEP if there is a possibility .

```
server.on("/L", HTTP_GET, [] 
(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
digitalWrite(led_gpio, LOW);                // GET /L turns the LED off
    esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(TIME_TO_SLEEP);
    esp_deep_sleep_start();

request->send(200, "text/plain", "ok");
});
```

I tried putting

```
   #define TIME_TO_SLEEP yourInputString =  readFile(SPIFFS, "/inputString.txt");
```

and i get this error

```
 'yourInputString' was not declared in this scope
```

I am a beginner in programming so be kind with me please . Thank you in advanced !

Answer (score 0):

If readfile gives back a number you can also call:

```
esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(readFile(SPIFFS, "/inputString.txt"));
```

With a define you usually declare something fixed. Because it’s dependent on the number in the file (which can change), it’s not usable. Not defined in that scope.

To prevent errors, make sure readfile always returns a number.

Comment: If i add line like in your exemple i get this error : `error: cannot convert 'String' to 'uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}' for argument '1' to 'esp_err_t esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(uint64_t)'
     esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(readFile(SPIFFS, "/inputString.txt"));`

Comment: So it gives back a string (text) instead of a number. Try to find a method to convert a string to a number, by google or here! :) Almost there.

Comment: If i read the file in the serial monitor the output of the text in `/inputInt.txt` is correct , but when i put in : `esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(readFile(SPIFFS, "/inputInt.txt").toInt());` it does not give errors but it returns 0

Comment: It converts a string to an integer, which is basically a good thing. Only, esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup uses very big numbers. Time is in microseconds. The input is uint64_t.  That means like a number which is not negative, could fit in 64 bits. 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 microseconds max, that’s a lot.. So if you return something like 60 seconds in your textfile, it translates in a positive way to 60 microseconds, practically zero. Or an error, because a normal Integer can only hold a much smaller number. (Because it also takes negative and less bits to translate the number)

Comment: To learn, try to print the value on your console. Like ESP_LOGI(“test”,”number is %d”, readFile(SPIFFS, "/inputInt.txt").toInt()); and experiment with some values. The trick is how to multiply it with 1000000 to get a proper input to the wake up time function. Try it!

Comment: Hi again RemyHx , you lost me with ESP_LOGI , i never used it, i searched over internet, but i do not understand how it works... any advice will be welcomed . Thank you for your answers!

Comment: It’s comparable to printf. Special for the ESP32 series. First parameter is a tag (string), second your text (string, with extra parameters like %d for numbers, %s for text, etc) and for every parameter you use a definition of the used parameters. Don’t get overwhelmed, just train by using. :)

Comment: Thank you RemyHx, i made it to work now! Good lesson! Thank you again!